# Issue with binding files in Kendo treeview for repeating folder names

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm new to kendo UI. I'm facing issue with binding a file in tree view having folder names are same. Instead of sitting file in 2nd repeated folder it sitting in 1st repeated folder. Like below.

1. Current display view

   [image: Current View]
2. Ema <0000/maa> new file should sit in 1.2 Application Form->Specific folder.

**P.S And i don't have id's for each folder/items in treeview**

Kindly help me to fix this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you bind the treeview once with all of the folders/files? If so, you can bind the treeview to the data where the files are each in their correct folder Items collection. If a file gets added, you can re-bind to the entire treeview data.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on a Dojo? I tried this, but it seems to be working: https://dojo.telerik.com/@GaloisGirl/AkEBelIW